# How to inject / load Angular directive in an app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My `main.js` is in the root folder of app.

```
-app
 |_ routes.js
 |_ main.js
-components
 |_directives
   |_abc-directive.js
```

How do I define a directive that can be added from another folder.

I tried this:

**`abc-directive.js`**:

```
var abcDirective = function() {
    // directive code
}
```

**`main.js`**:

```
app.main = angular.module('main', ['ngRoute', 'components.directives']);
app.main.directive('abcDirective', "<I don't want to define a directive here, 
                                      rather load from diff. folder>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your controllers, directives in their own modules and add those modules as a dependency to you main module

**abc-directive.js**

```
var app = angular.module('directives.abcDirective', [])

app.directive('abcDirective', ...
```

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['directives.abcDirective'])
```

You can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to manage dependencies..

Comment: Awesome. Will this work with Google Closure compiler?

Comment: Come and find me if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you load the `main.js`, which include the `main` module declaration, before the directive file.

You could register the directive in the directive file itself like this:

```
angular.module('main').directive('abcDirective', abcDirective);
```

Hope this helps.